# What went wrong?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-http

I am trying to import `akka-http` into my Scala project. I'm using IntelliJ as an IDE. The following is my `build.sbt`:

```
import sbt._

name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-experimental" % "1.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json-experimental" % "1.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %%"akka-http-testkit-experimental" % "1.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.5" % "test"
)
```

And this is the error I encounter:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.50 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.6 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.15 ...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-http-experimental_2.12;1.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-http-spray-json-experimental_2.12;1.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-http-testkit-experimental_2.12;1.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.12;2.2.5: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-http-experimental_2.12;1.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-http-spray-json-experimental_2.12;1.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-http-testkit-experimental_2.12;1.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.12;2.2.5: not found
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed Jul 13, 2017 6:14:02 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="file:/home/invictus/.IdeaIC2017.1/system/log/sbt.last.log">file:/home/invictus/.IdeaIC2017.1/system/log/sbt.last.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem like those libraries are available for Scala 2.12:

https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=akka+http+experimental

Answer (score 1):

You're using obsolete versions of those libraries. Akka HTTP is no longer experimental, and as of this writing, the latest version is [10.0.9](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/releases). Update your `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.9",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.0.9",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %%"akka-http-testkit" % "10.0.9",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.3" % "test"
)
```

Note that for ScalaTest, you have to upgrade to [3.x](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/) if you're using Scala 2.12.